# Slam gmapping problems

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Trying to do some mapping with a corobot Explorer robot. I have here the terminal output:
hmt@hmt-snowball:~/roscorobot-code/Corobot/corobot_teleop$ rostopic list
/PTZ/camera_info
/PTZ/image_raw
/PTZ/image_raw/compressed
/PTZ/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/PTZ/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/PTZ/image_raw/theora
/PTZ/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/PTZ/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/PhidgetMotor
/REAR/image_raw
/bumper_data
/camera/set_state
/camera/set_videomode
/camera_info
/diagnostics
/fix
/gripper_data
/hokuyo/parameter_descriptions
/hokuyo/parameter_updates
/image_raw
/imu_data
/infrared_data
/kinect/depth/image_raw
/kinect/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/odometry
/pantilt
/phidget_info
/position_data
/power_data
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/sonar_data
/spatial_data
/ssc32_info
/takepicture
/tf
hmt@hmt-snowball:~/roscorobot-code/Corobot/corobot_teleop$ rosbag record -O mydata position_data tf scan odometry
[ INFO] [1328743758.485130224]: Subscribing to position_data
[ INFO] [1328743758.491165610]: Subscribing to tf
[ INFO] [1328743758.496985339]: Subscribing to scan
[ INFO] [1328743758.505183982]: Subscribing to odometry
[ INFO] [1328743758.520783235]: Recording to mydata.bag.
hmt@hmt-snowball:~/roscorobot-code/Corobot/corobot_teleop$ rosbag play mydata.bag
[ INFO] [1328744171.896217826]: Opening mydata.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
[RUNNING]  Bag Time: 1328743924.828030   Duration: 166.118149 / 332.198020
hmt@hmt-snowball:~/roscorobot-code/Corobot/corobot_teleop$

So, as can be clearly deciphered, I recorded a bag file with the /tf and /scan topics. So, how do I use the gmapping utility to generate a map by playing the bag file?

Thanks,
-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12946/slam-gmapping-problems/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry guys, the issue was not any gmapping (Shocking, right?). It was the robot. The driver is messed up beyond my ability to repair. So, the company is fixing it.

Thanks anyway for your quick responses,
-Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you aware of the ['How to Build a Map Using Logged Data'](http://ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData) tutorial? This explains the basics. You can have a look at it and edit your question to be more specific if it still doesn't work.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Hunter,

As Stefan said, you can look at the well made tutorial.
Also if you are interested you can take a look at the launch file named gmapping.launch in the package corobot_state_tf, that is made to run gmapping on a Corobot. It may help you to understand how to launch gmapping. You should even be able to record the map in your bag file by launch this launch file.

---

Originally posted by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) with karma: 53 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1